# Excel VBA API GET request

Tags: json, excel, vba, shopify

I have made a GET request in VBA and I'm able to parse the first iteration of returned data into an excel sheet. However it will not start the second iteration.

A little more info:  I'm using Shopify API to get all Orders.  In Postman I can see multiple records for different orders (600+) in total.  I can parse all the information I need from the first returned order however I can't loop to the second.

I am use VBA-JSON library available here: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

I have posted my code below...

I can see that x is the total number of orders however increment V doesn't help me get onto the second order information.

```html
Sub ShopifyOrderAPI_GET()
Dim http As Object, str As Variant
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://SHOPNAME.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?status=any", False
        .Send
        str = Split(.responseText, "{""orders"": [ {")
        
    End With
    
    x = UBound(str)
    
    Dim JSON As Object
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each V In x
    V = 1
    
        Cells(V, 1) = JSON("orders")(1)("id")
        Cells(V, 2) = JSON("orders")(1)("email")
        Cells(V, 3) = JSON("orders")(1)("closed_at")
        Cells(V, 4) = JSON("orders")(1)("created_at")
        Cells(V, 5) = JSON("orders")(1)("updated_at")
        Cells(V, 6) = JSON("orders")(1)("number")
        Cells(V, 7) = JSON("orders")(1)("note")
        Cells(V, 8) = JSON("orders")(1)("token")
        Cells(V, 9) = JSON("orders")(1)("gateway")
        Cells(V, 10) = JSON("orders")(1)("total_price")
        Cells(V, 11) = JSON("orders")(1)("subtotal_price")
        Cells(V, 12) = JSON("orders")(1)("total_tax")
        Cells(V, 13) = JSON("orders")(1)("currency")
        Cells(V, 14) = JSON("orders")(1)("financial_status")
        Cells(V, 15) = JSON("orders")(1)("total_discounts")
        Cells(V, 16) = JSON("orders")(1)("total_line_items_price")
        Cells(V, 17) = JSON("orders")(1)("buyer_accepts_marketing")
        Cells(V, 18) = JSON("orders")(1)("name")
        Cells(V, 19) = JSON("orders")(1)("processed_at")
        Cells(V, 20) = JSON("orders")(1)("tags")
        Cells(V, 21) = JSON("orders")(1)("contact_email")
        Cells(V, 22) = JSON("orders")(1)("order_status_url")
        Cells(V, 23) = JSON("orders")(1)("discount_codes")(1)("code")
        Cells(V, 24) = JSON("orders")(1)("discount_codes")(1)("amount")
        Cells(V, 25) = JSON("orders")(1)("fulfillment_status")
        Cells(V, 26) = JSON("orders")(1)("tax_lines")(1)("title")
        Cells(V, 27) = JSON("orders")(1)("tax_lines")(1)("price")
        Cells(V, 28) = JSON("orders")(1)("tax_lines")(1)("rate")
        Cells(V, 29) = JSON("orders")(1)("tags")
        Cells(V, 30) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("title")
        Cells(V, 31) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("sku")
        Cells(V, 32) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("quantity")
        Cells(V, 33) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("price")
        Cells(V, 34) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("variant_title")
        Cells(V, 35) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("properties")(1)("name")
        Cells(V, 36) = JSON("orders")(1)("line_items")(1)("properties")(1)("value")
'        Cells(V, 37) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("name")
'        Cells(V, 38) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("address1")
'        Cells(V, 39) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("address2")
'        Cells(V, 40) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("city")
'        Cells(V, 41) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("zip")
'        Cells(V, 42) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("country")
'        Cells(V, 43) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("country_code")
'        Cells(V, 44) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("latitude")
'        Cells(V, 45) = JSON("orders")(1)("billing_address")(1)("longitude")
'        Cells(V, 46) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("name")
'        Cells(V, 47) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("address1")
'        Cells(V, 48) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("address2")
'        Cells(V, 49) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("city")
'        Cells(V, 50) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("zip")
'        Cells(V, 51) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("country")
'        Cells(V, 52) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("country_code")
'        Cells(V, 53) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("latitude")
'        Cells(V, 54) = JSON("orders")(1)("shipping_address")(1)("longitude")
    V = V + 1
    Next V
End Sub
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  Any assistance/guidance is much appreciated.

This is my first time working with APIs in VBA.

Comment: Your `v=1` inside the For... Next keeps resetting the `V = V + 1`. Probably better to use `for v=1 to UBound(str)`

Comment: ... also `LBound(str)` may be zero, not 1 unless you are intentionally trying to avoid a header.

Comment: Hi Jeeped thanks for your response.  I noted your comments re the loop, good spot, I had missed that.  I have corrected but still no luck.  Only returns one row, strange that now UBound(str) results to one rather than the max number of orders.